# Find two elements in an array, which occurs exactly once

Tags: c, algorithm, xor

Recently I was given the following task:

*Suppose you're given an array of elements of length **N** where every element except for two **special**, which appears once,  occurs exactly twice. Find this **special** numbers.*

I also know that every element in array is non-negative and is not more than 10^9 and the length of the array, **N** is less than or equal to 10^6

I think that the solution is using xors. Here is my thoughts:

Let's xor all elements in array. Since xor is commutative, e.g. xor(a, b)=xor(b, a), we can conclude that all elements which occurs twice will be zeroed:

xor(a, b, a, c)=xor(a, a, b, c)=xor(xor(a, a), b, c)=xor(0, b, c)=xor(b, c)

And then xoring whole array we'll get the xor of our two **special** elements.  What to do next? Maybe, some other solutions?

**P.S.** Please, don't tell me anything about hash tables. Firstly, I've tried it, but it didn't work, since my hash functions were not able to compress all range of numbers into array with any reasonable size(for my machine at least). Secondly, it is prohibited by task's condition.

**EDIT:** My bad, I didn't mention that sorted is also prohibited.

Comment: **0th thing to do**: sort the array

Comment: Sort it in `O(NlogN)` and then iterate it to find the two unique values in `O(N)`.

Comment: Can make a special ordering function that checks for equality and somehow stops the sorting process :)

Comment: XOR is just an implementation details, and not one that would make any difference, as you may as well use comparison. BTW, xor takes exactly 2 arguments, so your pseudo-code doesn't even make any sense.

Comment: Hashing won't solve the problem of course. First, its memory complexity would be way greater than sorting (9B vs 6M). Second, you'd still have to iterate the entire hash table at the end, so even the runtime complexity would be way greater (9B vs ~138M).

Comment: @goodvibration xor corresponds to addition in GF(2^k). Using xor with several arguments may be an abuse of language, but it is a common one, at least at the math (algorithmic) level.

Comment: Hashing won't solve the problem of course. First, its memory complexity would be way greater than sorting (9B vs 6M). Second, you'd still have to iterate the entire hash table at the end, so even the time complexity would be way greater (9B vs ~138M).

Comment: I wanna know whether dp approach is accepted or not?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Xoring in good approach.

Just think - what is result of xoring all elements? As you wrote, all paired elements are zeroed, so result is

```
 R = A xor B
```

Consider **one bits** of result `R` - we can see that they correspond to **distinct** bits of `A` and `B`.

So we can choose any non-zero bit of `R`, and make the second run - but xor only elements **having this bit non-zero**.

Now we have new result - it is equal or `A` either `B`.

Calculating the second one is elementary: `B = R xor A`

Complexity remains linear `O(n)`

Comment: Absolutely brilliant. In practice, this was of course not a "task" but an interview question, and in an interview I'd be quite happy if someone used a hash table to find _all_ items that occur an odd number of times. Also not usable for strings, for example.